Python: concise float format without losing order of magnitude
For easy comparison at a glance, statistical results in my project are usually best formatted as 0.3f, except (a) where decimal places are useless, or (b) where there is a small fraction such that the first 3 places are all zero. As of Python 3.11.8, there doesn't seem to be a built-in format that always gives the order of magnitude while minimizing useless digits. Using a loop over each character of a standard format, the result can be adjusted to meet these requirements, but it seems inefficient and unnecessarily detailed:
class FloatFormatter:
    def within(n, minimum, maximum):
        s = '{:.{m}f}'.format(n, m=maximum)
        decimal = truncate = False
        i = 0
        for c in s:
            i += 1
            match c:
                case '0':
                    continue
                case '.':
                    dot = i
                    decimal = True
                case _:
                    if (decimal):
                        truncate = True
                        break
        if decimal:
            places = (i - dot)
            if places < minimum:
                return s[:dot+minimum].rstrip('0') # minimum precision modulo trailing zeros
            if truncate:
                return s[:i].rstrip('0') # precision up to first non-zero
            if n > 1.0:
                return str(int(n)) + '.0_'
            else:
                return '* ' + '{:.0e}'.format(n)[1:] # sci-fi format with only the order of magnitude
        else:
            return s.rstrip('0').rstrip('.') # just the integer

Usage:
>>> x = 1.23456
>>> print("• x: " + FloatFormatter.within(x, 3, 10))
• x: 1.234

special case 1: show extra decimal places (up to 10) to preserve the order of magnitude
>>> x = 1.000023456
>>> print("• x: " + FloatFormatter.within(x, 3, 10))
• x: 1.00002

special case 2: precision 10 is insufficient to reach non-zero, so just show that it's slightly above zero
>>> x = 1.00000000000023456
>>> print("• x: " + FloatFormatter.within(x, 3, 10))
• x: 1.0_

special case 3: preserve the order of magnitude without giving more detail
>>> x = 0.00000000000023456
>>> print("• x: " + FloatFormatter.within(x, 3, 10))
• x: * e-13

Is there a simpler way to accomplish the same basic idea?

You can build a custom formatter for floats using a class like what you started with.  Instead of passing in the min and max decimal places each time, set it once and then let the object reference those values.
You can also override the __add__ and __radd__ methods to simplify the usage of the object where adding it to a float returns a formatted string.
class FloatFormatter:
    def __init__(self, min_sigfig: int=3, max_sigfig: int=10):
        self.min_sigfig = min_sigfig
        self.max_sigfig = max_sigfig

    def format(self, x: float) -> str:
        i = int(x)
        d = (x - i) if i >= 0 else -(x - i)
        dstr = str(d).replace('.','').lstrip('0')
        n = -math.log10(d) if d>0.0 else 0.1
        # handle exact power of 10
        if n.is_integer():
            n -= 1.0
        n = int(n)
  
        if n < self.min_sigfig:
            suffix = '0'*n + dstr[:self.min_sigfig-n]
        elif n <= self.max_sigfig:
            suffix = '0'*n + dstr[0]
        else:
            suffix = '_'
        return f'{i}.{suffix}'

    def __add__(self, other: float):
        return self.format(other)

    def __radd__(self, other: float):
        return self.format(other)

ff = FloatFormatter()

To use the formatter, just add it to a float:
>>> 1.012345 + ff
'1.012'
>>> 1.34567 + ff
'1.345'
>>> 1.00897 + ff
'1.008'
>>> 1.000000222 + ff
'1.0000002`
>>> 1.00000000000643 + ff
'1._'
>>> 1.0000000000000000000000000888 + ff  # this is beyond the precision limit
'1.'

It works with Pandas DataFrames as well:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'vals': [90.00000278, 8.992676, -23.29583, 110.0061, 0.00044738]})
df.vals + ff
# returns:
        vals
0  90.000002
1      8.992
2    -23.295
3    110.006
4     0.0004


Are you looking for significant figure formatting?
nums = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 10)**6
for n in nums:
    print(f'{n:.3g}')

0.531
0.0515
0.000998
0.0097
0.235
0.000131
1.9e-06
1.62e-06
0.0133
3.99e-05


That's close to the idea, but it's extremely distracting to have 1.9e-06 because, when quickly scanning a long column of numbers, it appears to be on the order of 2, whereas actually it is on the order of .0000002.
